# Appending spans to li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've this html

```
<div>
    <ul id="one"></ul>

</div>
```

And this code for appending `li` element to `ul`

```
$("#one").append("<li id='libtn2630275Chat'><img id='imgbtn2630275Chat' width='10' height='10' title='In Queue' alt='' src='/Content/themes/images/queue.png'/><input type='button' class='btnSend' id='btn2630275Chat' value='Jordan' onclick='fnBtnChatUserClick()' /><span id='spnPendingMessagebtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>(<span='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>0</span>)</span></li>");
```

Now the problem is that the last `)` is not added inside span `spnPendingMessagebtn2630275Chat`. See the attached image

[image]

Why it is not being included in the span, and how this can be resolved?

**Fiddle:** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/5stogo8m/)

Comment: Erm... your code says `</span>)` and you're wondering why it's outside the span?

Comment: `<span='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat'` ? At least use valid HTML.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol : `</span> is for the inside span, see properly

Comment: This post is not clear at all. Why you want to keep a bracket inside your dynamic DOM ???

Comment: You should create a fiddle. The image thing is not clear at all.

Comment: @blex : I too don't know why its being rendered like that :( please check the fiddle

Comment: blex is right - you have that actual text in your code - i presume you need id='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat' in the second span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line with this code:

```
$("#one").append("<li id='libtn2630275Chat'><img id='imgbtn2630275Chat' width='10' height='10' title='In Queue' alt='' src='/Content/themes/images/queue.png'/><input type='button' class='btnSend' id='btn2630275Chat' value='Jordan'  /><span id='spnPendingMessagebtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>(<span id='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat' class='display_None'>0</span>)</span></li>");
```

You forgot write 'id' before '=' in the span tag.

Comment: please mention what changes you did

Comment: you missed the id on your second span - the fiddle has it as <span='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>0</span>   it should be <span id='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>0</span>

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. my bad, missed id +1

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the id on the inner span has not been wriitern with the id attribute.

Add the id attribute to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. my bad, missed id +1

Answer (score 1):

Your span is not correctly defined :

```
(<span='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat' class='display_None'>0</span>)
```

You should not use that : `<span=....`

You probably miss the param name, like :

```
(<span id='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat' class='display_None'>0</span>)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. my bad, missed id +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works for me!

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.id="libtn2630275Chat";
li.innerHTML ="<img id='imgbtn2630275Chat' width='10' height='10' title='In Queue' alt='' src='/Content/themes/images/queue.png'/><input type='button' class='btnSend' id='btn2630275Chat' value='Jordan' onclick='fnBtnChatUserClick()' /><span id='spnPendingMessagebtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>(<span='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>0</span>)</span>"
document.getElementById("one").appendChild(li);
```

Look at my [Demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/xkphdd03/)

I Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The error is in code -

```
<span='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>
```

Try

```
<span id='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. my bad, missed id +1

Answer (score 0):

`<span='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat'` this part is not correctly formatted. Maybe you want to use `id=`?

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the "ID" attribute for the span. Check the below code

```
$("#one").append("<li id='libtn2630275Chat'><img id='imgbtn2630275Chat' width='10' height='10' title='In Queue' alt='' src='/Content/themes/images/queue.png'/><input type='button' class='btnSend' id='btn2630275Chat' value='Jordan' onclick='fnBtnChatUserClick()' /><span id='spnPendingMessagebtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>(<span id='spnPendingMessageCountbtn2630275Chat'  class='display_None'>0</span>)</span></li>");
```